# Shortest irreducible polynomials over $\Bbb F_p$ of degree $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

For any prime $p$, one can realize any finite field $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ as the quotient of the ring $\Bbb F_p[X]$ by the maximal ideal generated by an irreducible polynomial $f$ of degree $n$. By dividing by the leading coefficient, we may as well assume $f$ is monic, in which case we can write it as
$$f(X) = X^n + a_{n - 1} X^n + \cdots + a_1 X + a_0.
\def\co{\color{#00bf00}{1}}
\def\ct{\color{#0000ff}{2}}
\def\ch{\color{#bf00bf}{3}}
\def\cf{\color{#ff0000}{4}}
\def\ci{\color{#ff7f00}{5}}
$$

If we let $\zeta$ denote a root of $f$, then $\Bbb F_{p^n} \cong \Bbb F_p[X] / \langle f \rangle \cong \Bbb F_p[\zeta]$, and so when computing multiplication in this field and write elements as polynomials in $\zeta$ of degree $< n$, one way or another we use iteratively the identity
$$\zeta^n = -a_{n - 1} \zeta^{n - 1} - \cdots - a_1 \zeta - a_0.$$

Manually multiplying elements in this field is naively more efficient, then, when one chooses a polynomial $f$ with fewer nonzero coefficients.

So, naturally, we can ask just how efficient we can be:

> For any prime $p$ and any positive integer $n > 1$, what is the least number $\lambda(p, n)$ of nonzero coefficients an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over $\Bbb F_p$ can have?

Some general observations:

- The only polynomial of degree $n$ with exactly one nonzero coefficient is $X^n$, $\lambda(p, n) > 1$.
- Jim Belk's answer shows that there is an irreducible polynomial of the form $X^n + a$, that is, $\lambda(p, n) = 2$, if $p \not\mid n$ and $p$ has order $n$ modulo $n (p - 1)$. Thus, if these criteria do not hold for $(p, n)$, we have $\lambda(p, n) \geq 3$.

**Case $p = 2$.** Several behaviors are peculiar to the case $p = 2$. First, if $f(X) \in \Bbb F_p[X]$ has an even number of terms with coefficient $1$, then $f(1) = 0$ and so $f$ is divisible by $x - 1$, hence (if $\deg f > 1$) not irreducible. Thus, for $n > 1$, $\lambda(p, n)$ must be odd.

Some additional facts about this case:

- Swan has given several sufficient conditions for the reducibility of a trinomial $x^n + x^k + 1$ in $\Bbb F_2[x]$ (see citation below). One of these conditions in particular implies that all such trinomials are reducible when $n \equiv 0 \bmod 8$, and hence $\lambda(2, 8m) > 3$. More details can be found in $\S$40.9 of Jörg Arndt's *[Matters Computational](http://www.jjj.de/fxt/fxtbook.pdf)* (pdf warning, $>5$ MB).
- Ciet, Quiscater, and Siet [showed](http://www.dice.ucl.ac.be/crypto/publications/2002/poly.ps.) similarly that $\lambda(2, n) > 3$ if $n \equiv 13 \bmod 24$ or $n \equiv 19 \bmod 24$.

**Case $p \neq 2$.**

- If $n = 2$ and we write $p = 2 q + 1$, then $p^2 = (2 q + 1)^2 = 4q(q + 1) + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod {4 q} = 1 \pmod {2(p - 1)}$, so by Jim Belk's characterization, $\lambda(p, 2)$ = 2.
- Harry Altman gives a proof (generalizing an observation) below that for $p > 3$ we have $\lambda(p, 3) = 2$ for $p \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ and $\lambda(p, 3) = 3$ for $p \equiv 2 \bmod 3$.

These facts together give us:

- A characterization of $(p, n)$ such that $\lambda(p, n) = 2$.
- Knowledge of all $\lambda(p, n)$, $n \leq 3$.

It thus remains to determine which $(p, n)$ have $\lambda(p, n) > 3$ and $\lambda(p, n)$ for those values. Some naive experimentation suggests that it is rare for $\lambda(2, n) > 5$ and for $\lambda(p, n) > 3$ for $p > 2$.

A naive Maple script gives that the only values of $\lambda(n, p)$ that occur for $p < 2^5, n \leq 2^8$ are $2, 3, 4, 5$. Apparently minimal examples are:

\begin{array}{crrr}
\hline
\lambda(p, n) & p & n & f(X) \\
\hline
2 & 3 &  2 & X^2 + 1 \\
3 & 2 &  2 & X^2 + X + 1 \\
4 & 5 & 35 & X^{35} + X^4 + 4 X + 1 \\
5 & 2 &  5 & X^8 + X^4 + X^3 + X + 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}

For $p = 2$, [Table of Low-Weight Binary Irreducible Polynomials](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/98/HPL-98-135.pdf) gives minimal polynomials (and hence values $\lambda(2, n)$) for all $n \leq 10^5$. In all cases, $\lambda(2, n) \in \{3, 5\}$. See also OEIS [A057486](http://oeis.org/A057486), "Degrees of absolutely reducible trinomials, i.e. numbers $n$ such that $x^n + x^m + 1$ is factorable [modulo $2$] for all $m$ between $1$ and $n$."

> - What is the smallest degree $n$, if any, such that $\lambda(2, n) > 5$, i.e., for which there are no irreducible trinomials or pentanomials over $\Bbb F_2$?
> - If there is such a degree, what is the maximum value of $\lambda(2, n)$, if any?

Among $2 < p < 2^5$ and $n \leq 2^8$, the only values $\lambda(p, n) > 3$ are the following, and in each case $\lambda(p, n) = 4$:

\begin{array}{rl}
\hline
p & n \\
\hline
3 & 49, 57, 65, 68, 75, 98, 105, 123, 129, 130, 132, 149, 161, 175, 189, \\ & \quad 197, 207, 212, 213, 221, 223, 231, 233 \\
5 & 35, 70, 123, 125, 140, 181, 191, 209, 213, 219, 237, 249, 250, 253 \\
7 & 124, 163 \\
11 & 219 \\
17 & 231 \\
\hline
\end{array}

Searching $2 < p \leq 8161$ (the $2^{10}$th prime) and $n \leq 2^4$ yields no cases where $\lambda(p, n) > 3$.

> - What is the smallest $n$ such that $\lambda(p, n) \leq 3$ for all $p > 2$? (We know from the above that $4 \leq n \leq 35$.)
> - Is $\lambda(p, n) > 4$ for some $n$ and $p > 2$? If so, what is a minimal example, and what is the maximum value of $\lambda(p, n)$, $p > 2$?

*References*

Jörg Arndt, *[Matters Computational](http://www.jjj.de/fxt/fxtbook.pdf)* (pdf warning, $>5$ MB)

Mathieu Ciet, Jean-Jacques Quisquater, Francesco Sica, "A Short Note on Irreducible Trinomials in Binary Fields", (2002).

Gadiel Seroussi, ["Table of Low-Weight Binary Irreducible Polynomials,"](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/98/HPL-98-135.pdf) Computer Systems Laboratory HPL-98-135.

Richard G. Swan, "Factorization of polynomials over finite fields", *Pacific Journal of Mathematics*, **(12)** 3, pp. 1099-1106, (1962).

Comment: Interesting! I am curious a related question, is the set $\lambda(2,n), n\geq 1$ bounded?

Comment: Some $(p,n)$ beyond the scope of your table such that $\lambda(p,n) > 3$, i.e., there are no monic irreducible binomials or trinomials in $\mathbf F_p[x]$ of degree $n$, are $(p,n) = (3,49)$, $(3,57)$, $(5,35)$, $(5,70)$, $(7,124)$, and $(7,163)$.

Comment: @KCd How did you produce those examples?

Comment: @user119882 That's a good question. I don't know yet, but one can quickly see a sort of dual result, namely, that $\liminf_{n \to \infty} \lambda(2, n) = 3$, as $x^{2 \cdot 3^m} + x^{3^m} + 1$ is irreducible for all $m$.

Comment: For each $n > 1$ and $k$ running from $1$ to $n-1$, determine if $x^n + ax^k + b$ is irreducible as $a$ and $b$ run over $\mathbf F_p$ using a computer algebra package. Add $1$ if it is irreducible and add $0$ if it is reducible.  Then see for which $n$ the sum over all $k$, $a$, and $b$ is $0$. The calculations were carried out months ago, in order to find the first two $n$, for small $p$, when there are no irreducible binomials or trinomials over $\mathbf F_p$. (It included your data $n = 8$ and $n = 13$ for $p = 2$, but I hadn't mentioned it before.)

Comment: In particular, you're going to find $\lambda(3,n) \leq 3$ for $n \leq 57$ except at $n=49$ and $n=57$, $\lambda(5,n) \leq 3$ for $n \leq 70$ except at $n=35$ and $n=70$, and $\lambda(7,n) \leq 3$ for $n \leq 163$ except at $n=124$ and $n=163$.

Comment: @KCd Since the list of 2's I gave is exhaustive, it follows that $\lambda(p,n) = 3$ for all the remaining missing entries in the $p=3$, $p=5$, and $p=7$ rows in the table above.

Comment: @JimBelk, okay. It would be good if someone else could run through the calculations I made to verify numerically what I had found.

Comment: @KCd I just wrote a short Maple script and confirmed your results.

Comment: Then you can fill in the rest of your table for $p \leq 7$. Since the 2 and 3 entries swamp everything else, and should continue to do so as $n$ grows, make a table for each of the first few primes $p$ to separately indicate the $n$ up to $500$ or $1000$ where $\lambda(p,n)$ takes on different values greater than $3$. Trivially, of course, $\lambda(2,n)$ will never have even values.

Comment: With your new Maple script you should be able to fill in the rest of your table for the primes above $7$ without much effort. I would be a bit surprised if the currently missing entries do not all turn out to be $3$.

Comment: @KCd I have, and you're right, all of the remaining entries in the table bounds are $3$.

Comment: You colored the entries, which makes the table easier to read, but why make the number $3$ gray? It suggests that case is less important than when $\lambda = 2$. Give $3$ a more vibrant color, like red.

Comment: Not less important, just (by Jim's comment) more common.

Comment: @user119882 The answer remains unclear, but for $\n \leq 2^8$, $\lambda(2, n) \leq 5$ but $\lambda(2, n) = 5$ for $23$ such values.

Comment: @Travis I edited your post to add a 2 to the 49 column.  This should be the only 2 in the column.  (In general, a necessary condition for $\lambda(p,n)=2$ is that every prime divisor of $n$ also divides $p-1$, so all of the other $3$'s are correct.)

Comment: @JimBelk Thanks much. (Your comment also helped me discover a bug in my code for finding irreducible $m$-nomials of degree $n$ mod $p$, which failed for $m = 2$.)

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14787/, especially the paper [Table of Low-Weight Binary Irreducible Polynomials](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/98/HPL-98-135.pdf).

Answer (score 9):

Here is a helpful theorem:

**Theorem.** $\lambda(p,n) = 2$ *if and only if* $p \nmid n$ *and* $p$ *has order* $n$ *modulo* $n(p-1)$.

This tells us exactly where all of the 2's appear in the table.  Using a little *Mathematica* code, we can fill in the missing $2$'s:

\begin{array}{c|cccccccc}
\lambda & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20\\
\hline
      2 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 5 & 3 &  3 &  3 &  3 &  5 &  3 &  3 &  5 &  3 &  3 &  5 &  3 \\
      3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 &  3 &  3 &  3 \\
      5 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 2 &   &    &    &    &    &    &    &  2 & \\
      7 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 3 &   & 2 &    &    &    &    &    &    &    &     & 2 & \\
     11 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 2 &   &   &   &   &  2 &  3 \\
     13 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 2 &   & 2 & 2 &    &    &  2 &  3 &    &    & 2 &  & 2 &\\
     17 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 2 &   &   &   & 2 & & & & & & & & 2 & 3 \\
     19 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 &   & 2 &   &   & 2 & & & & & & & & & 2 & 3 \\
     23 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 3 &   &   &   &   &   & & 2 \\
     29 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 2 &   &   & 2 & 2 &   & & & & & 2 & & 2\\
     31 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 2 &   &   & 2 & 2 & & & & & 2 & & & 2 \\
\end{array}

*Proof:*  The proof is a generalization of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163364/prove-x5-2-is-irreducible-over-mathbbz-31/1163392#1163392) by Lubin. Let $p$ be a prime and let $n\geq 2$.

Note first that if $p\mid n$, then $x^n-\beta = (x^{n/p}-\beta)^p$ for all $\beta\in\mathbb{F}_p$, and hence $\lambda(p,n)>2$.  Therefore, we may assume that $p\nmid n$.

Let $\alpha$ be a primitive element of $\mathbb{F}_p$, and let $k=n(p-1)$.  Then $\alpha$ is a primitive $(p-1)$'st root of unity, so the polynomial $x^n-\alpha$ has at least one root $r$ that is a primitive $k$'th root of unity.  We claim that the following are equivalent:

1. $\lambda(p,n)=2$
2. $[\mathbb{F}_p(r):\mathbb{F}_p] = n$.
3. $x^n - \alpha$ is irreducible.
4. $p$ has order $n$ modulo $k$.

$(1) \Rightarrow (2)$ Suppose $\lambda(p,n)=2$.  Then $x^n - \beta$ must be irreducible for some $\beta \in\mathbb{F}_n$. Since $\alpha$ is primitive, we know that $\alpha^j = \beta$ for some $j$. Then $r^j$ is a root of $x^n-\beta$, so
$$[\mathbb{F}_p(r):\mathbb{F}_p] \;\geq\; [\mathbb{F}_p(r^j):\mathbb{F}_p] \;=\; n,
$$
and hence $[\mathbb{F}_p(r):\mathbb{F}_p] = n$.

$(2) \Rightarrow (3)$ and $(3) \Rightarrow (1)$ are immediate.

$(2) \Leftrightarrow (4)$ Let $m\geq 1$.  Then $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ contains the primitive $k$'th roots of unity if and only if $k \mid p^m - 1$, i.e. if and only if $p^m \equiv 1\;(\text{mod }k)$.  In particular, the smallest value of $m$ for which $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ contains the primitive $k$'th roots of unity is the order of $p$ modulo $k$.  Thus $[\mathbb{F}_p(r):\mathbb{F}_p]=n$ if and only if $p$ has order $n$ modulo $k$.$\quad\square$

Comment: Doesn't this run into a problem if $p\mid n$ (and hence $p\mid k$)?  In that case, in characteristic $p$, there is no primitive $k$'th root of unity.

Comment: Oh, silly me; if $p\mid n$, the order isn't defined -- you might want to rewrite the beginning as "$p\nmid n$ and $p$ has order $n$ modulo $n(p-1)$", for clarity!  Because that is true; if $p\mid n$, then $\lambda(p,n)\ge 3$ by a different argument, namely, Frobenius.

Comment: @HarryAltman Good point.  I've added that to the statement of the theorem for clarity, and I've added that case to the proof.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a proof of the pattern about $\lambda(p,3)$: As with degree $2$, a polynomial of degree $3$ is irreducible iff it has no roots, and there exists a noncube mod $p$ if and only if $p\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$.  So in this case we must have $\lambda(p,3)=2$.

Conversely, if $p\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, then we must have $\lambda(p,3)\ge3$.  But given a cubic irreducible polynomial mod $p$, since $p\ne 3$, we can perform a translation so that the coefficient of $X^2$ is $0$ (depressing the polynomial).  This shows that $\lambda(p,3)\le 3$ and so $\lambda(p,3)=3$.

This latter argument shows more generally that if $p\nmid n$, then $\lambda(p,n)\le n$, though this looks to be a pretty crappy bound.

Comment: Great, thanks for this observation. (But doesn't the second argument show that $\lambda(p, n) \leq n$ and not the strict inequality?)

Comment: Oops, silly me.  Off-by-one error.  Will Fix.  I should have noticed, given I just showed that in certain cases $\lambda(p,3)=3$!